# SQL query showing drastically different performance depending on the parameters

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

We have a stored procedure that searches products based on a number of input parameters that differ from one scenario to the next. Depending on the input parameters the search involves anywhere from two to about a dozen different tables. In order to avoid unnecessary joins we build the actual search query as dynamic SQL and execute it inside the stored procedure.

In one of the most basic scenarios the user searches products by a keyword alone (see **Query 1** below), which usually takes less than a second. However, if they search by a keyword and department (**Query 2** below), the execution time goes up to well over a minute, and the execution plan looks somewhat different (the attached snapshots of the plans are showing just the parts that differ).

**Query 1 (fast)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Product.ProductID, Product.Title 
FROM 
    Product 
    INNER JOIN ProductVariant ON (ProductVariant.ProductID = Product.ProductID) 
WHERE (1=1) 
    AND (CONTAINS((Product.*), @Keywords) OR CONTAINS((ProductVariant.*), @Keywords)) 
    AND (Product.SourceID = @SourceID) 
    AND (Product.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (ProductVariant.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus)
```

[image: Execution plan (quick query)]

**Query 2 (slow)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Product.ProductID, Product.Title 
FROM 
    Product 
    INNER JOIN ProductVariant ON (ProductVariant.ProductID = Product.ProductID) 
WHERE (1=1) 
    AND (CONTAINS((Product.*), @Keywords) OR CONTAINS((ProductVariant.*), @Keywords)) 
    AND (Product.SourceID = @SourceID) 
    AND (Product.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID)
    AND (Product.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (ProductVariant.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus)
```

[image: Execution plan (slow query)]

Both the Product and ProductVariant table have some string columns that participate in the full-text index. The Product table has a non-clustered indexed on the SourceID column and another non-clustered indexed on SourceID+DepartmentID (this redundancy is not an oversight but is intended). ProductVariant.ProductID is a FK to Product and has a non-clustered index on it. Statistics are updated for all indexes and columns, and no missing indexes are reported by SQL Management Studio.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this drastically different performance?

**P.S.** Forgot to mention that Product.DepartmentID is a FK to a table of departments, in case it makes any difference.

Comment: Looks like the slow one is doing the full text search repeatedly whereas the fast one just does it once and spools the result.

Comment: Martin, I had the same suspicion when I saw the 75% next to the full-text search in the slow plan. But how do I tell SQL Server to not do that and to follow the scenario it uses for the fast plan?

Comment: @CaspianCanuck have you gone thru this: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Materialising the matching primary keys from the full text search into a temp table and referencing that in the query instead will probably be easiest way.

Comment: @brykneval I don't see a catch all query there. The one with the extra search condition has an additional predicate. The where clauses aren't the same. A catch all query is when the same query is used for multiple scenarios.

Comment: @brykneval, thanks, but if you look closely you should see that my code does not use a catch-all query specifically for the reasons explained in the article.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck just to make sure, there exists another way of doing, but there is link embedded on that blog too, here it is this might be useful http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Comment: @MartinSmith just trying to hint him other ways of doing things too

Comment: @brykneval the hint is completely irrelevant because the OP is not using the practice that the article is about.

Comment: @MartinSmith, you were right on the money!  I am going to update my question with the solution based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSmith, please feel free to post your suggestion as an answer, and I will mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't the time at present. Feel free to post a self answer with what worked for you.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I already did, just wanted you to get the credit and earn some points. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MartinSmith for the suggestion to break the full-text search logic out into temp tables and then using them to filter the results of the main query. The following returns in just 2 seconds:

```
SELECT 
    [Key] AS ProductID
INTO 
    #matchingProducts
FROM 
    CONTAINSTABLE(Product, *, @Keywords)

SELECT 
    [Key] AS VariantID
INTO
    #matchingVariants
FROM
    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductVariant, *, @Keywords)

SELECT DISTINCT
    Product.ProductID, Product.Title 
FROM 
    Product 
    INNER JOIN ProductVariant ON (ProductVariant.ProductID = Product.ProductID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #matchingProducts ON #matchingProducts.ProductID = Product.ProductID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #matchingVariants ON #matchingVariants.VariantID = ProductVariant.VariantID
WHERE (1=1) 
    AND (Product.SourceID = @SourceID) 
    AND (Product.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (ProductVariant.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (Product.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID) 
    AND (NOT #matchingProducts.ProductID IS NULL OR NOT #matchingVariants.VariantID IS NULL)
```

---

Curiously, when I tried to simplify the above solution using nested queries as shown below, the results were somewhere in-between in terms of speed (around 25 secs). Theoretically, the query below should be identical to the one above, yet somehow SQL Server internally compiles the second one differently.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Product.ProductID, Product.Title 
FROM 
    Product 
    INNER JOIN ProductVariant ON (ProductVariant.ProductID = Product.ProductID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Key] AS ProductID
        FROM 
            CONTAINSTABLE(Product, *, @Keywords)
    ) MatchingProducts 
    ON MatchingProducts.ProductID = Product.ProductID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Key] AS VariantID
        FROM
            CONTAINSTABLE(ProductVariant, *, @Keywords)
    ) MatchingVariants 
    ON MatchingVariants.VariantID = ProductVariant.VariantID
WHERE (1=1) 
    AND (Product.SourceID = @SourceID) 
    AND (Product.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (ProductVariant.ProductStatus = @ProductStatus) 
    AND (Product.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID) 
    AND (NOT MatchingProducts.ProductID IS NULL OR NOT MatchingVariants.VariantID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Just an update to the above solution:

The SQL works fast as it is unless the full-text search returns a lot of keyword matches, in which case the speed drops precipitously due to the lack of PK indexes on the two temp tables. To fix this I updated my code to create the two temp table ahead of times with non-clustered PK indexes, then do a INSERT... SELECT... instead of SELECT... INTO, and now it works like a charm all the time.

Answer (score -1):

This may have been your mistake

> In order to avoid unnecessary joins we build the actual search query as dynamic SQL and execute it inside the stored procedure.

The dynamic SQL cannot be optimized by the server in most cases. There are certain techniques to mitigate this. Read more [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Get rid of your dynamic SQL and build a decent query using proper indices. I assure you; the SQL Server knows better than you when it comes to optimizing. Define ten different queries if you must (or a hundred).

Secondly... Why would you ever expect the same execution plan when running different queries? using different columns/indices? The execution plans and results you get seem perfectly natural to me, given your approach.

You will not get the same execution plan / performance because you are not querying column 'DepartmentID' the first query.

Comment: Searching by DepartmentID alone returns results in a split second. Searching by keyword alone is very fast too. Yet doing both takes a ridiculous amount of time.

And this difference cannot be blamed on dynamic SQL because I get the same results when I repeatedly execute these two queries directly as stand-alone queries outside of the stored procedure.

Comment: You stated "The Product table has a non-clustered indexed on the SourceID column and another non-clustered indexed on SourceID+DepartmentID". You are using different indices on each query. look the second execution plan for the big fat 75% at the bottom.

Comment: Try removing the composite index  SourceID+DepartmentID and create a new one for  DepartmentID. Leave the SourceID as it is. My guess is that you may get better results that way. Also, I can ont fully inspect your execution plans and see the CPU and time consumed.

Comment: Ricardo, yes, I can clearly see that. But that big fat 75% is for the full-text search, which theoretically should have nothing to do with the other branch of the execution plan tree that searches the Product table by DepartmentID.

Comment: I have already tried indexing DepartmentID alone and it made no difference whatsoever. Note in the second (slow) execution plan how the index seek on IX_Product_Department (the composite index) doesn't really take that much time, %-wise. That's what stumps me.

I will see if I can attach the execution plans in full detail here.

Comment: Why do you state that dynamic sql can't be optimized by the server? Dynamic sql will cause an execution plan to be created just like any other query. The problem here is that plan is attempted to reused when the parameters change. Simply adding an OPTION RECOMPILE would get rid of that issue.

Comment: IX_product_department Vs IX_product_sourceID, I see it. Guessing again; the culprit seems IX_product_department as a composite index, it may need to be rebuilt, and statistics rebuilt also. Again, delete the composite one and create single ones instead. I suggest.

Comment: I've tried using OPTION (RECOMPILE) but it made no difference whatsoever. Also, the index was freshly rebuilt before my tests, as were the statistics. 

I think Martin Smith is on to something though.

Comment: @SeanLange that discussion is too long for just these comments. While dynamic SQL should be avoided, it can be mitigated with `exec sp_executesql` more in the subject here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22932/why-you-want-to-avoid-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Agreed the topic is entirely too long for here. I just commented because you stated it can't be optimized which really is not accurate. I certainly wouldn't recommend for something like the OP is doing. Also, the downvote was not me. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I do see your point, while my statement seems harsh, my thought is that since he is using different parameters on each query, he was not using sp_execute, but I could be wrong. I probably could reword that better.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck When you said "I have already tried indexing DepartmentID alone and it made no difference whatsoever." you need to delete the composite index, or the new one may not even get used. Hard to say from here, with no access to your systems.

Comment: @RicardoC, yes, I dropped the composite index before indexing on DepartmentID alone. MartinSmith's suggestion was right on the money though, but I thank you and all others who took the time to answer my question anyways! :)

Comment: @CaspianCanuck I am glad you find a solution =) I will delete my answer later on, since it seems to add no much value.

Comment: @RicardoC, I wouldn't delete it because your suggestions may be perfectly valid and applicable for someone else's situation.